# Finding equation of a plane passing through a point and an intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

I have to find equation of a plane passing through a point $M(3,1,2,1)$ and a line $l$ which is intersection of the planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

The elements are in the extended euclidean space $E_3^*$

$$
l: \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha: x+y=0  \\
\beta: y+z-t=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

OK, my reasoning is the following. I have to find two points passing through the line $l$, for example $N(1, -1, 1, 0)$ and $P(-2, 2, -1, 1)$ I can form a determinant

$$
    \begin{array}{|cccc|}
x & y &z & t & \\
3 & 1 &2 & 1 &\\
1& -1 & 1 & 0 &\\
-2 & 2 & -1 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

which when solved will give the equation of the desired plane.

Is this reasoning correct? Also, is this like using the fact that the vector product of 3 point points is 0 when they are coplanar?

Comment: What Kind of Point is this $$M(3,1,2,1)$$?

Comment: Your choice of words seems to hint that this happens in three-dimensional space, but your math is four-dimensional. You should get one of them straight. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That notation usually means that the point $M$ has the coordinates $(3,1,2,1)$.

Comment: Yes, this is extended euclidean three dimensional space, so there's a forth dimension for t for infinite points. I'll add a comment clarifying this.

Comment: Oh, so we're in projective three-dimensional space. That's specifically _not_ Euclidean, though.

Comment: Do you mean you work in projective space $\mathbf P^3(\mathbf R)$?

Comment: @Bernard I guess I do. My notes are using the $E^*_3$ notation but I can switch to $P^3(R)$ if it's more known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Another approach  is this:

A plane through the intersection line of planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belongs to the pencil of planes defined by $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and a plane in this pencil has equation
$$\lambda(x+y)+\mu(y+z-t)=0$$
for some $\lambda,\mu$ not both $0$ (actually $(\lambda,\mu)$ are unique up to a non-zero factor, i.e. they define a point in $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R)$.

Then, a plane in the pencil passes through $M(3,1,2,1)$ if and only if
$$\lambda(3+1)+\mu(1+2-1)=0,$$
whence the ration $\lambda/\mu$.